# What good does a Steppable Pipeline

Tags: powershell, pipeline

In our company were I am quiet new, they have a wrapper for almost every Native PowerShell cmdlet mainly to add more logging and error handeling. I am trying to push back on this and also refer to internal PowerShell feature to create a proxy command like:

```
$GCI = Get-Command Get-ChildItem
[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create($GCI)
```

But I am lacking some knowledge here.
What is difference (if any) between a SteppablePipeline and using the native PowerShell syntax.
In other words, in the `Process` block, what is the difference between:

```
$steppablePipeline.Process($_)
```

and using the native PowerShell syntax:

```
$_ |Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Get-ChildItem # In this example
```

I am aware that I am seeking for general information but it appears to me that there is hardly any  information on e.g. the [`ScriptBlock.GetSteppablePipeline` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.getsteppablepipeline)

Comment: Well, `$someStuff |A-Command` will automatically call `Begin()` once, then `Process()` for each input item, then `End()` - with `SteppablePipeline` you get direct control over this flow. If you don't need that then obviously you don't need one

Comment: Thanks @Matthias, logically. I guess that is actually the answer as simple as it is.

Comment: @Mathias would be nice to have the comment as answer to the question :)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I agree, but it's gonna be a few hours before I have the time to write up a proper answer ^_^

Comment: When you do `$_ | SomeCommand` inside your command, you create a _nested_ pipeline. With steppable pipeline you can actually _chain_ SomeCommand into the pipeline, that your command is part of. This can be a performance improvement (e. g. when SomeCommand does expensive `begin` and `end` processing). In some cases you can provide correct results only by using steppable pipeline (e. g. when SomeCommand is one of the `Format-*` cmdlets, which need to see the entire input).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This venerable blog post from 2009](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/extending-andor-modifing-commands-with-proxies/), which introduced ***proxy functions*** (wrapper functions), explains that **steppable pipelines are required to implement them**; the following quote suggests (but doesn't explicitly state) that they may have been created for that very purpose:

> In particular, what you want to have happen is to be able to control the execution of the calling command – to control when it’s BEGINPROCESS(), PROCESSRECORD(), ENDPROCESS(), etc methods are called

Simply put, **proxy functions, via steppable pipelines**, allow you to **implement a cmdlet (advanced function) by delegating most of the implementation to *another* cmdlet *in a memory-efficient, streaming manner***.

Specifically, a steppable pipeline allows you to delegate the implementation of your proxy function to a script block whose *life cycle is kept in sync with the proxy function itself*, in terms of initialization (`begin` block), per-object pipeline input processing (`process` block), and termination (`end` block), which means that the *a single instantiation of the wrapped cmdlet* is in effect *directly connected to the same pipeline as the proxy function itself*.

Conversely, this means: you don't strictly need a *proxy* function to write a wrapper function in the following scenarios:

- If your wrapper function doesn't need to support pipeline input.
- If you don't mind collecting all pipeline input *first*, before passing it all to the wrapped cmdlet *at once*, in your wrapper function's `end` block, which means that you're forgoing *streaming* processing

  - While you *may* also get streaming processing if you call the wrapped cmdlet *for each input object* in your `process` block, doing so:

    - is *inefficient* (a full invocation of the wrapped cmdlet in every iteration, in a nested pipeline)
    - *doesn't work* for cmdlets that need to operate on *all* input *as a whole*, such as `Format-*` cmdlets or aggregating cmdlets such as `Sort-Object` and `Group-Object`

---

The following are **three different implementations of a wrapper function** around `Select-String`, which reports only the matching part of each matching line, as a string, to illustrate the tradeoffs:

- `Select-MatchProxy` is a proper proxy function, i.e. it calls `Select-String` via a steppable pipeline, which amounts to streaming processing that only involves a *single* call instantiation of `Select-String`.

  - It is based on a stripped-down version of the scaffolding code that `[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create((Get-Commmand 'Select-String'))` generates.
  - [GitHub issue #10863](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10863) discusses potential improvements to the code that [`[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand.Create) generates.
- `Select-MatchSimple` calls a new `Select-String` instance in each `process` block, which also amounts to streaming processing, but performs poorly; as noted above, this implementation approach isn't always feasible, depending on what cmdlet is being wrapped.
- `Select-MatchCollect` collects all pipeline input up front, and then passes it to `Select-String` in the `end` block, which forgoes streaming processing and is memory-intensive; however, in terms of *runtime* it actually performs slightly better than the proxy function.

```bash
function Select-MatchProxy {
  [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    $InputObject,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0)]
    [string] $Pattern
  )
  begin {
    $steppablePipeline = { 
       Select-String -Pattern $Pattern | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
     }.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
    $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
  }
  process {
    $steppablePipeline.Process($InputObject)
  }
  end {
    $steppablePipeline.End()
  }
}

function Select-MatchSimple {
  [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    $InputObject,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0)]
    [string] $Pattern
  )
  process {
    Select-String -InputObject $InputObject -Pattern $Pattern |
      ForEach-Object {
        $_.Matches.Value
      }
  }
}

function Select-MatchCollect {
  [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    $InputObject,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0)]
    [string] $Pattern
  )
  begin {
    $l = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
  }
  process {
    $l.Add($InputObject)
  }
  end {
    $l | Select-String -Pattern $Pattern | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
  }
}
```

To **compare runtimes**, you can use the following code:

```bash
# Sample input array of 100,000 strings.
$array = ('foo', 'bar') * 50000
# Time 15 runs of each function, and report the average.
Time-Command { $array | Select-MatchProxy   'o+' }, 
             { $array | Select-MatchSimple  'o+' }, 
             { $array | Select-MatchCollect 'o+' }
```

Sample timings from a macOS 12.4 M1 Mac running PowerShell Core 7.3.0-preview.6, which give a sense of relative performance:

```
Factor Secs (15-run avg.) Command                           TimeSpan
------ ------------------ -------                           --------
1.00   0.916              $array | Select-MatchCollect 'o+' 00:00:00.9162298
1.12   1.025              $array | Select-MatchProxy   'o+' 00:00:01.0254835
5.38   4.930              $array | Select-MatchSimple  'o+' 00:00:04.9298495
```

The above uses the `Time-Command` function from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27).

- Assuming you have looked at the linked Gist's source code to ensure that it is safe (which I can personally assure you of, but you should always check), you can install it directly as follows:

  ```bash
  irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27/raw/Time-Command.ps1 | iex
  ```

Comment: In some examples I see `$myInvocation.CommandOrigin` being passed to `GetSteppablePipeline()`. Can you explain when this is necessary? It seems to be related to runspaces, but I couldn't find any explanation how its behaviour would change according to the argument.

Comment: @zett42, good question, that is actually also how the `[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create($Cmd)` method does it,.

Comment: @iRon, good point: I've updated the answer to include this argument, and, separately, I've linked to a GitHub issue discussing improvements to the generated code.

Comment: @zett42, good point; please see my previous comment. I personally don't know why it's necessary and what it does, and the docs don't help.

Comment: Stackoverflow is really a place where I learned a lot. Not from just questioning but also answering. I started to use Stackoverflow about a decade ago mainly for PowerShell issues and as this **What good does a Steppable Pipeline** question, I had only a little suspicion what the answer could be but with the full explanation, I was able to answer somebody else's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74997412/1701026) and contribute to the PowerShell Community blog: [Mastering the (steppable) pipeline](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/mastering-the-steppable-pipeline/).