# How to define a command alias in PowerShell for filtering output?

Tags: windows, powershell, filter, select-string

I need to define an alias for this:
`Select-String -NotMatch -Pattern "^[\t ]+\d"`

so that I can use the alias instead of writing that long string each time.
After googling for 5 minutes and doing some experiments I came up with this:

```
filter foo {
    $_ | Select-String -NotMatch -Pattern "^[\t ]+\d"
}
```

So now my script looks like this:

```
command1 | foo
command2 | foo
command3 | foo
command4 | foo
```

This is apparently working as expected, but I'm concerned about the efficiency implications of doing this.
Is the `foo` filter acting as a transparent alias of the longer command line, or is it creating an entire new pipe or buffer or something?

Comment: I wouldn't be too concerned about performance. A filter function is just a shortcut for writing an advanced function that processes pipeline input in its `process{}` block. Though there might be a functionality issue, depending on your use case. As you are creating a sub pipeline within the function, which processes each input object individually, the function will fail if the input is formatted (e. g. output of `Format-Table`). If you have a need to support formatted input you would have to write a proxy (wrapper) function. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73074477/7571258

Comment: This should be a steppable pipeline. Your current implementation is invoking `Select-String` per input object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the `foo` filter acting as a transparent alias of the longer command line, or is it creating an entire new pipe or buffer or something?

The latter, your current implementation is invoking `Select-String` per pipeline input object instead of invoking it once and processing all input. If you care about performance you should change your implementation for a steppable pipeline:

```bash
function steppablefoo {
    param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] $InputObject)

    begin {
        $pipe = { Select-String -NotMatch -Pattern '^[\t ]+\d' }.GetSteppablePipeline()
        $pipe.Begin($PSCmdlet)
    }
    process {
        $pipe.Process($InputObject)
    }
    end {
        $pipe.End()
    }
}
```

You can test it for yourself with this performance comparison:

```
$tests = @{
    Filter = {
        0..300kb | foo
    }
    SteppablePipeline = {
        0..300kb | steppablefoo
    }
}

$tests.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Test              = $_.Key
        TotalMilliseconds = (Measure-Command { & $_.Value }).TotalMilliseconds
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76396561/45375):

A **simpler - but limited - alternative** is to use a simple (as opposed to [advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced)) `function` (not `filter`). The limitations are:

- Due to use of the [automatic `$input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input) and no per-input-object processing, *all input is collected in memory up front*, whereas the steppable-pipeline solution in Santiago's answer preserves the *streaming* behavior of `Select-String`.

  - This implies that display output won't start until a given input command has emitted *all* its objects.
- You may pass any additional parameters to pass through to [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-String) *ad hoc* (on invocation), via the [splatted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) form of the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) (`@args`), but you won't get *tab completion*.

  - For tab-completion support, you could duplicate `Select-String`'s parameter declarations, which is cumbersome, however.
  - An *automated* way to duplicate them is to use [`[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create((Get-Command 'Select-String'))`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand.Create) to scaffold your function - but that is the very way to define a *proxy* function, as shown in simplified form in Santiago's answer. You may therefore just as well create such a proxy function rather than the simplified form below. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73074477/45375) for more information about proxy functions.

```
function foo { $input | Select-String -NotMatch -Pattern '^[\t ]+\d' @args  }
```