# How to make sure a file used by a steppable pipeline is closed even in case of an exception?

Tags: powershell, pipeline, powershell-core, powershell-7.3

This is a **self-answered** question. I'm going to add an answer only for **PowerShell 7.3 or newer**. Feel free to add answers for any previous PowerShell version.

---

I have a custom logging function that accepts pipeline input and uses a **steppable pipeline** object to correctly forward its input to `Out-File`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73074477/7571258) provides background why a steppable pipeline is required in this case. Also see the blog post [Mastering the (steppable) pipeline](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/mastering-the-steppable-pipeline/).

When any command of the pipeline of which my logging function is part of, **throws an exception** (aka *script-terminating error*) and the exception is caught, the file opened by `Out-File` doesn't get closed and any subsequent attempt to add something to the file (e. g. using `Add-Content`) fails with the error message:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\LogFile.log' because it is
> being used by another process.

Here is a **reproducible example**:

```bash
$LOG_FILE_PATH = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot LogFile.log

Function Test-SteppablePipeline {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter( Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline )]
        [string] $InputObject
    )

    begin {
        Write-Host '[begin]'

        $steppablePipeline = {
            Out-File -LiteralPath $LOG_FILE_PATH
        }.GetSteppablePipeline( $MyInvocation.CommandOrigin )

        $steppablePipeline.Begin( $true )
    }

    process {
        Write-Host '[process]'
        
        $steppablePipeline.Process( $InputObject )

        $InputObject  # Forward to next command in pipeline of caller
    }

    end {
        Write-Host '[end]'

        $steppablePipeline.End()
    }
}

try {
    'foo', 'bar' | 
        ForEach-Object { throw 'my error' } |
        Test-SteppablePipeline
}
catch {
    '[catch]'
}

Write-Host '[add]'
Add-Content -LiteralPath $LOG_FILE_PATH -Value 'baz'
```

**Output:**

```
[begin]
[process]
[catch]
[add]
Add-Content: C:\Test.ps1:48
Line |
  48 |  Add-Content -LiteralPath $LOG_FILE_PATH -Value 'baz'
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The process cannot access the file 'C:\LogFile.log' because it is being used by another process.
```

As you can see by the `[messages]`, the `end` block of `Test-SteppablePipeline` doesn't get called because of the exception, which propably is the reason why the file doesn't get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A notable mention:** This isn't an issue of *just* the steppable pipeline but an issue for any PowerShell function that obtains a [handle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_(computing)) and needs to ensure that said handle is properly disposed before exiting.

---

This is a big problem that got solved in PowerShell 7.3 with the `clean` block as [zett42 points out in his helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77282824/15339544). For anyone wondering how this problem is solved in PowerShell 7.2 and previous versions, the answer is, *it can't be solved with just PowerShell*, the solution is to create a binary cmdlet that implements the [`IDisposable` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-7.0), the engine will do the rest (ensuring that `.Dispose()` is called invariantly, including <kbd>CTRL + C</kbd> or a terminating error).

A minimal repro of zett42's code using a binary cmdlet. Note that for the sake of demo, this is using `Add-Type` and inline C# for compiling at runtime, ideally, this cmdlet would be precompiled.

```bash
Add-Type '
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace Test
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "SteppablePipeline")]
    public sealed class TestSteppablePipelineCommand : PSCmdlet, IDisposable
    {
        private SteppablePipeline _pipe;

        [Parameter(Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true)]
        public string InputObject { get; set; }

        protected override void BeginProcessing()
        {
            WriteInformation("[begin]", null);
            _pipe = ScriptBlock.Create("Out-File -LiteralPath $LOG_FILE_PATH")
                .GetSteppablePipeline(MyInvocation.CommandOrigin);
            _pipe.Begin(true);
        }

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            WriteInformation("[process]", null);
            _pipe.Process(InputObject);
            WriteObject(InputObject, enumerateCollection: true);
        }

        protected override void EndProcessing()
        {
            WriteInformation("[end]", null);
            _pipe.End();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _pipe.Dispose();
        }
    }
}' -PassThru -IgnoreWarnings -WA 0 | Import-Module -Assembly { $_.Assembly }

$LOG_FILE_PATH = Join-Path $pwd.Path LogFile.log

try {
    0..10 |
        Test-SteppablePipeline -InformationAction Continue |
        ForEach-Object {
            if ($_ -eq 5) {
                throw 'my error'
            }
        }
}
catch {
    '[catch]'
}

Write-Host '[add]'
Add-Content -LiteralPath $LOG_FILE_PATH -Value 'baz'
Get-Content $LOG_FILE_PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution for **PowerShell 7.3 or newer** is trivial. PowerShell 7.3 adds a [`clean`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.3#clean) block to *advanced* functions. Citing from the documentation:

> The `clean` block is a convenient way for users to clean up resources
> that span across the `begin`, `process`, and `end` blocks. It's semantically
> similar to a `finally` block that covers all other named blocks of a
> script function or a script cmdlet. Resource cleanup is enforced for
> the following scenarios:
>
> 1. when the pipeline execution finishes normally without terminating error
> 2. when the pipeline execution is interrupted due to terminating error
> 3. when the pipeline is halted by `Select-Object -First`
> 4. when the pipeline is being stopped by <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd> or `StopProcessing()`

When using a *steppable pipeline*, you simply call the [`.Clean()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.steppablepipeline.clean?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) method of the steppable pipeline object from within the `clean` block of the function that uses the steppable pipeline:

```bash
$LOG_FILE_PATH = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot LogFile.log

Function Test-SteppablePipeline {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter( Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline )]
        [string] $InputObject
    )

    begin {
        $steppablePipeline = {
            Out-File -LiteralPath $LOG_FILE_PATH
        }.GetSteppablePipeline( $MyInvocation.CommandOrigin )

        $steppablePipeline.Begin( $true )
    }

    process {
        $steppablePipeline.Process( $InputObject )

        $InputObject  # Forward to next command in pipeline of caller
    }

    end {
        $steppablePipeline.End()
    }

    clean {
        # Makes sure the resources (e. g. files) allocated by the steppable pipeline 
        # are freed even in case of exceptions (script-terminating errors).
        $steppablePipeline.Clean()
    }
}
```

Comment: Zett why would you accept my answer, mine was just informative / complimentary. Your answer should be the accepted one 

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yours links to mine, so it's two-in-one.  Cheers!